# PHPUnit_Framework_Exception: Creating default object from empty value

Tags: php, yii, phpunit, codeception

I'm devising a codeception test to load a component,.... I have the following test file

```
<?php
namespace tests\codeception\common;
use Yii;

class FoursquareTest extends \Codeception\TestCase\Test
{
    public $appConfig = '@tests/codeception/config/common/unit.php';

    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();

        $config = [
            'components' => [
              'foursquare' =>
              [
                'class' => 'garyrutland\foursquare\Foursquare',
                'clientId' => '',
                'secret' => ''
              ]
            ]];
        Yii::configure(Yii::$app, $config);
    }
    // tests
    public function testSearch()
    {
      //$this->assertInstanceOf('garyrutland\\foursquare\\Foursquare', Yii::$app->foursquare);
    }

    public function fixtures()
    {
        return [
            'foursquare' => [
                'class' => FoursquareFixture::className()
            ],
        ];
    }

}
```

But when I run

```
codecept run unit FoursquareTest.php -vv
```

I get

> PHPUnit_Framework_Exception: Creating default object from empty value
>
> #1  /path/to/htdocs/yii/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/BaseYii.php:518
>
> #2  /path/to/htdocs/yii/tests/codeception/common/unit/FoursquareTest.php:22

I instantiate the Foursquare class directly though there is no problem....

Whay do i gee the created Object Error

Comment: It happens in BaseYii::configure() because Yii::$app is null.